# I want to compare the (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString()) with 1,2,3,4 : but does not Work?? show me error

Tags: c#

```
void check_User()
{
       string username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1].ToString();
       MessageBox.Show(username);

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select User_Name,FK_RoleID from SO_User_Table where User_Name='" + username + "'", cn);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       try
       {
           da.SelectCommand = cmd;
           da.Fill(dt);
           if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed , Please Contact Your Administrator");
           }
           else if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("You are not allowed , Please Contact Your Administrator");
           }
           else if

            (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
               if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() == 1)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Your Are Admin");
               }
               else if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() ==2)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("You are SM");

               }
               else if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() ==3)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("You are Sales");
               }
               else if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() ==4)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("You are SalesMgr or Director");
               }

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // lblInfo.Visible = true; 
           //lblInfo.Text = "There is an Error!!! please contact administrator. (" + ex.Message + ")"; 
       }
       finally
       {
           dt.Clear(); da.Dispose(); dt.Dispose(); cn.Close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting? Make it easier for people to help you by being clear about what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is.For one you're trying to compare an int to a string.

Comment: Let's hope little Bobby Tables doesn't need a login to this ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() == 1)
{               
    MessageBox.Show("Your Are Admin");
}
etc.
```

You are comparing a string to an int?

I'd try to unbox dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1] by prefixing (int), or by comparing with "1" like

```
if ((int)dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() == 1)
```

or

```
if (dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString() == "1")
```

Comment: good point - I've tried to tell ibrahim a gazillion times to be a better SO citizen, but he doesn't seem to want to listen....

Comment: @marc_s and that too politely

Comment: I appreciate your sentiments, but removing helpful information (and leaving a note as to why) really doesn't help people who find this question via Google. If you really want the post removed, flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two things that clearly stand out:

1. dt.Rows will only contain 1 record at that point in code, yet you're accessing the 2nd.

   ```
   dt.Rows[1]
   ```

   Should read:

   ```
   dt.Rows[0]
   ```

   I suspect given this, that you actually mean ItemArray[0] also, but without seeing your data I can't be sure.
2. You're calling ToString() on the item, and then trying to compare it to a number. Either convert it to an integer, or compare it to a string.

   ```
   Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]) == 2
   ```

   Or

   ```
   dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == "2"
   ```